# How to revert to one line terminal in new Kali Linux 2020.04

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux, bashrc

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$
```

I want this to be in one line on terminal like it was before I updated kali.
I tried changing bashrc on kali user and on root user there was no update.

Comment: I have Kali 2020.4 VM here; Kernel 5.8.0.  I use Xfce and Terminal is 0.14.1 .  It is all single line. What version of Terminal are you using?

Comment: @gronostaj I tried changing it in my ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash.bashrc with my user or with root, when I change it in script so that script does not contain \n (new line) still does not work, even if I delete whole code terminal still stays the same

Comment: @John Im not quite sure how to get that info when I do uname -r I get this info "5.9.0-kali1-amd64"
And when I do my dmesg | grep Linux I get this info "Linux version 5.9.0-kali1-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.0-15) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.1) #1 SMP Debian 5.9.1-1kali2 (2020-10-29)"

I'am using VMware Kali

Comment: What you see appears to be the new approach for new installs.   https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-2020-4-release/  I upgraded in place, so my terminal has not changed.

Comment: @John yeah so far I understand that they just said how to get new look of the terminal not how to revert it, new line in terminal is bugging me so much

Comment: Probably nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I just did a full dist-upgrade and Kernel is now 5.9 so I know that all worked. I am using QT5 Terminal and Xfce Windows Manager (to look like Windows 10) and terminal is all single line. So if you like the setup you have, you will likely have to live with the two line terminal. Kali startup is now very tacky but once running it is OK. So Kali is apparently adapting to most users desires.

Comment: @John Actually I just managed to do it, I saw in bash.bashrc that of you use zsh shell youll get new terminal look, but if your shell is bash youll get the old one liner and I switched to bash with chsh -s /bin/bash and rebooted my VM so I got the old look and no annoying suggestions before I finish typing but its so weird that you cannot change it in ~/.bashrc 
Anyway thanks for help everyone

Comment: This does not magically come from the Terminal. Since you run _bash_, it is defined via the variable `PS1`. You are responsible for setting this  variable in a reasonable way. For an experiment, do on the command line a `PS1='\d \s \w >' and verify that the prompt indeed changed. For the safe side, also do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` and let us know what version you get from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `.zshrc` file and change the variable PROMPT like so:

```
PROMPT=$'%F{%(#.blue.green)}${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)──}(%B%F{%(#.yellow.blue)}%n%(#..㉿)%m%b%F{%(#.blue.green)})-[%B%F{reset}%(6~.%-1~/…/%4~.%5~)%b%F{%(#.blue.green)}]%B%(#.%F{yellow}#.%F{blue}$)%b%F{reset} '
```

You can also get rid of the newline between prompts. Just change this variable to "no":

```
new_line_before_prompt=no
```

While I was at it I also changed the color red to yellow, because It was popping out too much to me.

In order for the changes to take effect you must restart the Terminal or execute `source ~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 3):

Very easy solution! Type in the terminal `kali-tweaks`, then go to `shell and prompt` then `configure prompt` move cursor to `one line` and press <kbd>space</kbd> then apply and you’re done!

Answer (score 1):

Three options are there so you can choose your preferred configuration, as depicted below
first, edit the zshrc with your favorite editor; after that, replace the **PROMPT_ALTERNATIVE** and **NEWLINE_BEFORE_PROMPT** accordingly.

```
$ nano ~/.zshrc
```

[image: 0xfk :kali prompt config 0xfk]

[image: 0xfk :kali prompt oneline]

When done refresh the terminal to apply the new changes

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

Second option as highlighted by @user1678412  is to use kali-tweaks following the steps below:

```
$ kali-tweaks
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kali has very simple command utility for this purpose:

```
kali-tweaks
```

source:

````
https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/```
````

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, if you would like to revert to a simple one liner (without blue brackets and parentheses or icons):

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Then edit the line to be

```
PROMPT='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}%B%F{%(#.red.blue)}%n%(#.@.@)%m%b%F{reset}:%B%(6~.%-1~/…/%4~.%5~)%b%B%(#.%F{red}#.%F{blue}$)%b%F{reset} '
```

Would also recommend turning off `$new_line_before_prompt`

Comment: The order of answers is not fixed, therefore "the above answer" does not describe any specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use **bash** instead of **zsh**. Since you already edited the `.bashrc` file, just run `bash` in the prompt to test your edits. To make permanent, you can edit `/etc/passwd`, making `/usr/bin/bash` your default shell:

```
┌──(rootblackbox01)-[~] 
└─# vim /etc/passwd
... 
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash  ##<< instead of /usr/bin/zsh
...
### reboot
...
root@blackbox01:~#
root@blackbox01:~#
```

Comment: Do not edit `/etc/passwd` by hand. Use `chsh` to change your login shell. If you really need to edit `passwd` then do it with `vipw`.

Comment: Hey @KamilMaciorowski I respect your caution, but can you explain why? Is it just to better avoid typos in the passwd or is there some other reason?

Comment: @JayRugMan Correct. There is always some level of risk in directly changing the `passwd` file.

Comment: I'm always careful... been doing this for over a decade without an issue.. both privately and professionally, on dozens of systems. (shh... I also log into root more than I use sudo - don't tell the Linux gods).

Comment: First, `chsh` and alike are usable by users on their own account (hence no need to switch to `root` or use `sudo` and alike.) Second, those tools and `vipw` (that also checks that the format isn't broken) take care of backup and shadow files (plus the distro specifics)

Answer (score 0):

In `~/.zshrc` there's a kali config variable named `PROMPT_ALTERNATIVE`, possible values oneline, twoline (default value) and a keybinding `^P` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) is associated with it.

Using this one can toggle between the two possible alternatives.

[image: img1: in dot zshrc config file]
[image: img2: observable change on terminal interface]