# How do I change the location of my terminal username in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, kali-linux

When I use terminal in Kali linux, my username is located above the line I enter commands in and is not to the left of the command line as it for most users. I can't find the setting that changes this - does anyone which setting changes this?

Thanks!

[image: See this image for visual of problem]

Comment: Try checking your user's `~/.zshrc` file compared to the other users' configuration file (based on screenshots online - see [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/kali-linux-basic-commands) for example, I think that the way you have it is the way it comes by default in Kali Linux

Comment: Also see the answers in https://superuser.com/q/1603642/368970 for the specific things to configure.